# Inductive proof that $(m!^n)n! \mid  (mn)!$ 

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I have worked this problem out before but am stuck on the inductive step.

> Show that $(m!^n)n! \mid  (mn)!$

I am using induction on $n$.

I thought to factor $(m(n+1))$! but can't get it exactly how I want it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $(m!^n)n\mid(mn)!$, say $(mn)!=a(m!^n)n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\big(m(n+1)\big)!&=(mn+m)!\\
&=(mn)!\prod_{k=1}^m(mn+k)\\
&=a(m!^n)n!\prod_{k=1}^m(mn+k)\\
&=a(m!^n)n!(mn+m)\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}(mn+k)\\
&=am(m!^n)(n+1)!\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}(mn+k)\;.
\end{align*}$$

If you can now show that $$(m-1)!\;\Bigg\vert\;\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}(mn+k)\;,$$ you’ll have the extra factor of $m!$ that you need.

HINT: $\dbinom{mn+m-1}{mn}$ is an integer.

Comment: Aha! I had gotten to the last line algebraically, but that was the key I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you're not interested in non-inductive proofs, please ignore this answer.

If you are, note that you can view the group $S_m\wr S_n$ (that squiggly symbol is the [wreath product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product)) as a subgroup of $S_{mn}$.  These groups have cardinality $(m!)^nn!$ and $(mn)!$, respectively.  The statement you want is [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) applied to this pair.

Comment: Amazing. I need to learn Wreath product though!

Comment: @KannappanSampath: While wikipedia defines $\wr$, it could perhaps be more explicit.  For the purposes of this answer, view $S_{mn}$ as permutations of $mn$ items arranged in a grid with $m$ rows and $n$ columns.  Then $S_m\wr S_n$ is the subgroup consisting of all permutations which rearrange columns in an arbitrary way and rearrange elements within each column in an arbitrary way.  You can rearrange the $n$ columns in $n!$ ways and rearrange the elements of each of the $n$ columns in $m!$ ways, so $\lVert S_m\wr S_n\rVert = (m!)^nn!$.

Comment: This sort of provides me the intuition. I meant that, I don't know the construction of the wreath product. So, I'll have to learn that formally. But, I am thankful to you for the intuition. I love your answer and the explanation.

Comment: A link to your answer is posted on my profile here. Particularly a good answer. I have known applications like this: For instance $n! \mid \binom n 0 _2$, by considering the symmetric group as a subgroup in $\operatorname {GL}(\mathbb F_2)$, the homomorphism given by the permutation matrices.

But, however I could not think of this, because I never knew the way to work with Wreath Product!

Comment: @KannappanSampath: It looks like we both have something to learn from each other about this trick.  What does the notation $\binom{n}{0}_2$ mean?

Comment: $\binom n 0_2:=|\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb F_2^n)|=(2^n-1)(2^n-2)(2^n-4) \cdots (2^n-2^{n-1}$. I am sorry that $n$ went missing in my previous comment and may have well served as the source of confusion. Particularly, this $\binom n 0_2$ is called the Gaussian Binomial 2-coefficient and a binomial $q$-coefficient for $q$ a prime power is defined in a similar way. And the limit of the coefficient as $q \to 1$ is the binomial coefficient!

Comment: @KannappanSampath: Thanks!