# Proving $m!(n!)^m \mid (mn)!$ and $m!n!(m+n)! \mid (2m)!(2n)!$ algebrically

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> $\def\legendre{\genfrac(){.5pt}{}}$Let $m,n$ be positive integers. Prove the following -
>
> - $m!(n!)^m \mid (mn)!$
> - $m!n!(m+n)! \mid (2m)!(2n)!$

First one is here - [Inductive proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105823/inductive-proof-that-mnn-mid-mn)
I can give a combinatorial proof. $\frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}$ is the way to split $mn$ things in $m$ groups of $n$ things.
I am looking for algebric proof of both statements.
**My Work**
Let $p$  be any prime
Then it suffices to prove $\legendre{m}{p} + m\legendre{n}{p} \leq \legendre{mn}{p}$ and $\legendre{m}{p} + \legendre{n}{p} + \legendre{m+n}{p} \leq \legendre{2m}{p} + \legendre{2n}{p}  $ But don't know how to prove these.
It is easy to see if $p \gt min(n,m)$ then it comes obvious. But how to prove when $p \leq min(n,m)$
I'd also like to know if their exists any combinatorial prove of the second statement.
**P.S**: Don't give only hints. I need a full solution. I am messing up things.

Comment: Why is the tag (legendre-symbol) or (linear-algebra) necessary?

Comment: @S.C.B. I think we need legendre-symbol while proving it algebrically.

Comment: I think that you are going to need the floor function, not the legendre-symbol, as quadratic residues don't seem very helpful here.

Comment: As far as I have seen, there are no known combinatorial proofs of the second result.  The only proof I have seen is based on the inequality $$\lfloor 2x\rfloor+\lfloor 2y\rfloor \geq \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor+\lfloor x+y\rfloor$$ for all $x,y\geq 0$.  The first result, on the other hand, has an easy combinatorial proof.

Comment: @S.C.B. I didn't know that there is a floor-function tag :|

Answer (score 1):

One can see that the Bivariate Catalan Number is defined by

$$C(m,n) := \frac{ (2m)!(2n)!}{m!n!(m+n)!} = \frac{\binom{2m}{m} \binom{2n}{n}}{\binom{m+n}{n}}$$

Comment: Choosing $m$ objects from $2m$ and $n$ objects from $2n$, I think that should be $\binom{2m}{m}\binom{2n}{n}$.     
Can you explain why the divide by $\binom{m+n}{n}$?

Comment: the Bivariate Catalan Number is an integer always so ...

Comment: I was talking about the previous edit

Comment: Why you said Choosing $m$ objects from $2m$ and $n$ objects from $2n$ ?

Comment: How is saying something is an integer an explanation for how it's an integer?